# How to get return value of turn on GPS Location?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, google-location-services

Here I am using LocationServices for turn on GPS on xamarin android

```
 try
            {
                MainActivity activity = global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context as MainActivity;

                GoogleApiClient googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(activity).AddApi(LocationServices.API).Build();
                googleApiClient.Connect();
                LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.Create();
                locationRequest.SetPriority(LocationRequest.PriorityHighAccuracy);
                locationRequest.SetInterval(10000);
                locationRequest.SetFastestInterval(10000 / 2);

                LocationSettingsRequest.Builder
                    locationSettingsRequestBuilder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
                    .AddLocationRequest(locationRequest);
                locationSettingsRequestBuilder.SetAlwaysShow(false);
                LocationSettingsResult locationSettingsResult = await LocationServices.SettingsApi.CheckLocationSettingsAsync(
                  googleApiClient, locationSettingsRequestBuilder.Build());

                if (locationSettingsResult.Status.StatusCode == LocationSettingsStatusCodes.ResolutionRequired)
                {
                    locationSettingsResult.Status.StartResolutionForResult(activity, 0);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
```

But I want to get the return value from this code.

this code will open a Turn on Location popup,if user turn on then I want to get the bool value from this.But from where I can get the bool value for user accepted for turn on location or not.

here is the popup

[image]

how to get the value from this popup?

Comment: Call the Android native code via a Forms' dependency service and return a "Status" value to your Forms' app : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction

Comment: @SushilHangover I think you didn't understand my qustion.I am asking that from which line I will get my return?

Comment: `...I want to get the return value from this code...` ??? You have the return, its the  `LocationSettingsResult` instance.

Comment: @SushilHangover But this code exection completed,so from where I get the the value? this popup is not awaited.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ask user to turn on Location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43138788/ask-user-to-turn-on-location)

Comment: You get the call in `OnActivityResult` check the duplicate comment it has the Xamarin implementation

Comment: @Vidhya did you get the solution?

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, you want to get return value when you click OK or No, THANKS from Location popup, am I right?

If yes, I suggest you can install **plugin.permission** to check status. Looking the following code, if you click OK, **status == PermissionStatus.Granted**. If you click NO,Thanks, **status=PermissionStatus.Denied**.

```
 private async void OnCheck(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            var status = await CrossPermissions.Current.CheckPermissionStatusAsync<LocationPermission>();
            if (status != PermissionStatus.Granted)
            {
                if (await CrossPermissions.Current.ShouldShowRequestPermissionRationaleAsync(Permission.Location))
                {
                    await DisplayAlert("Need location", "Gunna need that location", "OK");
                }

                status = await CrossPermissions.Current.RequestPermissionAsync<LocationPermission>();
            }

            if (status == PermissionStatus.Granted)
            {
                //Query permission
            }
            else if (status != PermissionStatus.Unknown)
            {
                //location denied
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Something went wrong
        }
    }
```

Comment: I know this is this is another process,but I need to check this every second for this process.