# How do I Ask users to enable device location inside my app if it wasn't enabled ? - unity

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, gps

I'm writing a simple script in unity C# where I retrieve latitude and longitude and then do stuff with it

```
 IEnumerator Start()
{
    // First, check if user has location service enabled
    if (!Input.location.isEnabledByUser)
        yield break;

    // Start service before querying location
    Input.location.Start();

    // Wait until service initializes
    int maxWait = 20;
    while (Input.location.status == LocationServiceStatus.Initializing && maxWait > 0)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
        maxWait--;
    }

    // Service didn't initialize in 20 seconds
    if (maxWait < 1)
    {
        print("Timed out");
        yield break;
    }

    // Connection has failed
    if (Input.location.status == LocationServiceStatus.Failed)
    {
        print("Unable to determine device location");
        yield break;
    }
    else
    {
        // Access granted and location value could be retrieved
        print("Location: " + Input.location.lastData.latitude + " " + Input.location.lastData.longitude + " " + Input.location.lastData.altitude + " " + Input.location.lastData.horizontalAccuracy + " " + Input.location.lastData.timestamp);
    }

    // Stop service if there is no need to query location updates continuously
    Input.location.Stop();
}
```

The problem with is code that it works but only if the user is already enabled device location.
If device location is not enabled,then this code is simply dead. I'm trying to find a why where if device location is not enable, a similar prompt to this will be shown instead:

[image]

Now pressing ok will enable device location without existing the app, and that what i'm trying to do here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many explanation about this topic. You can examine this!
 [Turn on location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43138788/ask-user-to-turn-on-location)